# Eliminate rows using multiple if clauses

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have the following database:

```
ID   x   y    
1    23  -3  
2    2   51  
3    -2  45  
4    NA   2  
5    NA  -2  
6    NA  NA
```

I want to eliminate all the rows with negative values on the columns x and y, but I want to keep the NAs (that are written as the special value in R).

The result should be the following:

```
ID   x   y    
2    2   51    
4    NA   2   
6    NA  NA
```

I have tried using:

```
database <- database[!(database$x < 0 && database$x != "NA" || database$y < 0 && database$y != "NA")]
```

But it does not work, as it gives the error

> 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Which, from what I have seen, should be a problem of the new R version.
I have also tried using `!is.na()`, and substituting `&&` and `||` to `&` and `|`, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are doing double negation, which is not necessary. Just flip the sign in the comparison statement (i.e. `database$x < 0` to `database$x > 0`). Also, to index a dataframe, you need `database[row, column]`, where in your code, you are missing the index for column.

```
database[(database$x > 0 | is.na(database$x)) & (database$y > 0 | is.na(database$y)),]
```

Or with the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

database %>% filter(if_all(x:y, ~ .x >0 | is.na(.x)))
```

#### Output

```
  ID  x  y
2  2  2 51
4  4 NA  2
6  6 NA NA
```